# Datatables defaults of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm working with some datatables and I keep getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
```

I've done some searching and from what I read it had to do with the order of the files. However, I am calling them in the right order...

Is there another cause for this?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.3/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
```

The datatable looks like this

```
var commentTable = $('.commentTable').DataTable({
            aoColumns: [
                {
                    "mData": "name",
                },
                {
                    "mData": "date",
                },
                {
                    "mData": "comment",
                },
    ],
            bSort: false
        });
```

Comment: Can you show the code so we can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @FrankerZ, I added the datatable. It's breaking before it gets to the table though

Comment: Alright, pull up the stackoverflow code snippet editor, and try to give us a reproducible issue in there. That would be the **best** way to get a solid answer.

Comment: @FrankerZ, this has to do with a plugin and linking to see if I missed something. This is breaking before it gets to any code. The answers I have researched say that the above linking is correct and that is why I am confused.

Comment: You have added mData, but there is no sAjaxSource specified to refer? Are you doing ajax call?

Comment: @Sagar, Yes, this is within an ajax call. But it is breaking before it gets there and makes the call. It is breaking before any code is called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but you are loading an older version of Datatables:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

I suggest 1.10.16 instead of 1.10.10.  It could be 1.10.10 doesn't support a feature needed for one of the other extensions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your support on DataTables forums is outstanding!

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't the issue. I still don't know what is causing this. I even tried commenting out all the 'extensions' and just use datatables main file, but that didn't work.